# Form opens in new iframe

Tags: php, html

I've got a problem. I have got two servers on first I've got my whole db with login page, and on secoud one I've got my WWW page. Those servers are on diferent domains. I build site, where is 2 iframes, each iframe respectively from first and secoud server. When I submit form the results are opening in new tab instead of place results in the secound one. Belowe is code. I will add only that, on IE it works good.
secound server

index.html (this is the main frame)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>New Web Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <iframe name="vforms1" src="vforms.php" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
        <iframe name="map1" src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx/map.php" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

vforms.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["variable"])){
    $var2 = $_POST["variable"];
   echo $var2;
}
else echo 'waiting';
?>
```

first server
map.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://xxx.xxx.xxx/test/vforms.php" method="POST" target="vforms1">
<input type="hidden" name="variable" value="send"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working on that since last friday, and try to do everything! Now it's realy drive me crazy! Can anybody help me?
Cheers!

Comment: Why do you need iframes? Why not access the database from the primary web server?

Comment: I cant connect directly to db due of security policy and lots of  other stuff in my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is on a different domain, there are cross domain policies in place. The `<form>` does not know about the other iFrame, and cannot access it. Neither can it access it's parent.

So, there really is no option on how to fix it, other than remotely connecting to the database with php, and removing the iFrames all together (which is a bad thing in the first place)

Comment: Not how you currently want it. I highly recommend connecting to the mysql database remotely

Comment: as I written before there is no option to do this. But I worked it out by creating a virtual directory and changing adress like it was on the same domain.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you should be using the frameset doctype inside a framed document? You may be rendering the target attribute invalid.

Comment: it's a cross domain issue, as the iFrame content is on a different server/url